# Looking for a list of German word roots

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, dictionary, morphology

I'm trying to automate word splitting for German, and given that there are some articles on wiktionary for [prefixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_prefixes) and [suffixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_suffixes)
(English versions seems to contain more than German ones for some reason), the only thing missing is roots...

Therefore I'm looking for anything (paper, book, article) which can summarize German roots – maybe Stammwörterbuch? Like here: https://studyflix.de/deutsch/wortfamilie-4781, but more detailed, maybe a dictionary?

Thank you

Comment: that's called *stemming*, wiktionary is probably not the best source and why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Regarding your underlying problem ("I'm trying to automate word splitting for German") - would you be able and willing to use Python? If so, you could use the spacy package which solved this problem already - https://spacy.io/

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "splitting"? This term is ambiguous. Clearer terms are [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) (it's [Stemming](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) also in German) and hyphenation or more precise: [syllabification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification) (Silbentrennung or better [Worttrennung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worttrennung) in German.) Stemming operates on morphemes, i.e. parts of words that carry certain meanings or grammatical function. But syllabification operates on phonetic properties of sequences of sounds or letters.